# Divisões calculando errado em C

Tags: c, float, double

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double A, B;
    double MEDIA;
    scanf("%f", &A);
    scanf("%f", &B);
    MEDIA = (A + B)/2;
    printf("MEDIA = %5f", MEDIA);
    return 0;
}
```

Neste programa eu já compreendi que o problema é que o `scanf()` não consegue ler variáveis `double`. Então, ao mudar o tipo primitivo das variáveis `A` e `B` para `float`, ao invés de `double`, o programa funciona corretamente como deveria. Porém eu PRECISO que leia as variáveis em `double`. Eu não sei como resolver, não sei nem se há jeito de resolver, já que por algum motivo, não achei nada falando sobre leitura de variáveis `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não vejo necessidade alguma para este tipo de dado ser `double`, mas vou considerar que é um requisito sem sentido de exercício (na verdade pode dar ligeira diferença, se precisar de exatidão nem um desses dois tipos pode ser usado), então o correto é usar o formato de *long float*  para receber o dado como `double`. Aproveitei para mudar o nome de variável para ficar dentro do padrão que se usa.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double a, b;
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    scanf("%lf", &b);
    printf("MEDIA = %5f", (a + b) / 2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FSThmK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ScanfFormatDoublec). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ScanfFormatDouble.c).

Note que no `printf()`não precisa porque há *cast* automático. No `scanf()` não pode acontecer porque é um ponteiro que é recebido.

Comment: Caso interessante que scanf() é diferente de printf(). Em printf() o %f serve para o double pelo fato de printf() aceitar número variável de parâmetros, enquanto scanf() usa máscaras diferentes para float, double e long double.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Maniero. Resolveu o problema que estava em dúvida. Mas acredita que não era esse o problema a ser resolvido no exercício? Pensei que fosse esse o problema, e mesmo depois de conseguir resolver nesta parte, não foi este o problema que não me deixava passar no exercício. Mas muito obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: Eu também não entendi esta parte de ser necessário ler as variáveis em double, mas já que o exercício pede assim, não vou duvidar, kkkk.